# finding peaks in a vibration signal

Tags: python, graph, signals, signal-processing

I am new in python and I just graduated and my thesis was about vibratory analysis, so when I started learning python. I wanted to make an an app that reads the signal and gives spesific informations about the graph such as peaks, here is what I have for now

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import filedialog as fd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
    import numpy as np
    import os
    
    Raw_1 = []
    Raw_2 = []
    clean_1 = []
    clean_2 = []
    
    
    # create the root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Yazid ")
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.geometry("400x400")
    # full screen
    class FullScreenApp(object):
        def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
            self.master = master
            pad = 3
            self._geom = "200x200+0+0"
            master.geometry(
                "{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
                    master.winfo_screenwidth() - pad, master.winfo_screenheight() - pad
                )
            )
            master.bind("<Escape>", self.toggle_geom)
    
        def toggle_geom(self, event):
            geom = self.master.winfo_geometry()
            print(geom, self._geom)
            self.master.geometry(self._geom)
            self._geom = geom
    
    
    def select_file():
        filetypes = (("text files", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*"))
        # get the txt file
        filename = fd.askopenfilename(
            title="select file", initialdir="/", filetypes=filetypes
        )
    
        # Get the raw list
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            lines = [i for i in line.split("       ")]
            Raw_1.append(lines[0].replace(",", "."))
            Raw_2.append(lines[1].replace(",", "."))
        # clean means get rid of the first three lines
        for item in Raw_1[3:]:
            clean_1.append(item)
        for item in Raw_2[3:]:
            clean_2.append(item)
        # convert to float (geting the X and Y axes)
        x = [float(i) for i in clean_1]
        y = [float(i) for i in clean_2]
    
        # plotting the points
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.subplots()
        ax.plot(x, y, color="r")
        ax.grid()
    
        # naming the x axis
        plt.xlabel(Raw_2[0])
        # naming the y axis
        plt.ylabel(Raw_1[0])
    
        # title graph
        fname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        name = os.path.basename(fname)
        plt.title(name)
    
        # Defining the cursor
        cursor = Cursor(ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, useblit=True, color="r", linewidth=1)
    
        # Creating an annotating box
        annot = ax.annotate(
            "",
            xy=(0, 0),
            xytext=(-40, 40),
            textcoords="offset points",
            bbox=dict(boxstyle="round4", fc="linen", ec="k", lw=1),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>"),
        )
        annot.set_visible(False)
    
        # function to show the plot
        plt.show()
    
    # open button
    open_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Open a File", command=select_file)
    
    open_button.pack(expand=True)
    
    
    # run the application
    root.mainloop()
```

I am removing the first three lines because the first line contains the name of each column and the next two lines have some transient (I have more than 1600 values)

My code gives the following result

[image: RESULTS]

I want it to mark those peaks and give me their value on the y axes

and thank you

Comment: TPeak finding is a challenging topic.  There are many different algorithms, each of which performs best in different situation.  You will also need to consider if you need to filter out noise before applying peak finding.  Anyhow, a good first attempt is to look at how the  slope changes - when it goes from +ve to -ve then you have an indication of a peak.  FYI here is an screenshot of the GUI for one of my peak finding apps. https://github.com/JamesBremner/windex/raw/master/doc/controlpanel.png

Comment: Looking at your test data ( the picture just appeared ), the slope detection algorithm is not reccomended for such tall, narrow peaks.  I would recommend a algorithm called "tall poppy" which is triggered when the data goes above and then below a specified value within a short time.

Comment: @ravenspoint as you said my peaks are way too tall because they have been extracted from a gearbox of a milling machine i tried looking for tall poppy but coudlnt find anything about tall poppy just poppy and its docummentation doesn't have anything about an algorithm called tall poppy do you have a documentation for it ?

Comment: The Tall Poppy, as I have implemented it for a client, are proprietary.  However the basic concept is very simple and you should be able to develop your own implementation from the brief description I posted.

Comment: thanks i'll try it if i can't understand the find_peaks method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with [scipy.signal.find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html). In the documentation you will find how to do an example like this.

[image]

The orange crosses are the points selected with `find_peaks`, you have several parameters to tune, and it will probably be more productive than if you try to implement from scratch. After that if your can do a better job what is done by that function you can contribute to the library with your implementation.

Comment: i tried using find peaks but i still dont understand scipy.signal so i am trying to find another way or someone that could help me in integring it into my code

Comment: That's why I pointed linked the documentation, I am sure that if you was able to write the code you shared, if you take some time to understand the `find_peaks` function you will be able to get it to work. It seems that you are new to the community. If you Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time. Also check the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn about the buttons on the site, specially accepting the answers and indicating usefulness.

Comment: yes i am new, i just didnt give it time i think am going to give it more time and understand, i'll also read what you pointed out about the buttons on the comunity thank you again for you answer i'll accept your answer because its what i need to learn in order to achieve my goal thanks again